# xls to xlsx conversion using vba name statement corrupts the file

Tags: vba, excel, rename, corrupt

I am trying to rename a file from `abcd.xls` to `xyz.xlsx` using the following code-

```
  NumOfAttachments = Range("RecCount").Value
  DestinationFolderPath = Range("destinationfolder").Value
  NewShtName = "Sheet1"

  If NumOfAttachments <> 0 Then
    For X = 0 To NumOfAttachments - 1
      OrigName = Range("Startcell").Offset(X, 1).Value
      NewName = Range("startcell").Offset(X, 2).Value
      SourceFolderPath = Range("startcell").Offset(X, 3).Value
      NewFile = DestinationFolderPath & NewName
      If Dir(DestinationFolderPath & OrigName) <> "" Then Kill DestinationFolderPath & OrigName
      FileCopy SourceFolderPath & OrigName, DestinationFolderPath & OrigName

      If Dir(NewFile) <> "" Then Kill NewFile
      Name DestinationFolderPath & OrigName As NewFile
```

After this when I try to open the file(`xyz.xlsx`) I get the following error-

`excel cannot open the file xyz.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid`

Comment: Can you [edit] to post more of your code? I don't see anything there that would actually rename a file. (You do know that just renaming it doesn't convert it from an `.xls` to an `.xlsx` file, right? It's still an `.xls` file.)

Comment: I have posted the entire code. Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

The reason is very simple. You are not using the correct file format.

Your `.SaveAs` code should look like this

```
.SaveAs "\myserver\test\xyz.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

See the below table for File Formats

```
50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2010 with or without macro's, xlsb)
51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro's in 2007-2010, xlsx)
52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro's in 2007-2010, xlsm)
56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2010, xls)
```

Would recommend this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx)